# Confused why getting ClassCircularityError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

I've developed a utility project for reading and writing excel files and I've added it's compiled output as a jar file to my main project. I have named this utility jar file as: **MyUtils.jar**.

Also I'm developing an ADF web Project and I'm deploying it as a `war` package on `weblogic 10.3.5`. I'm using `ADF-11g` release `11.1.1.4` in my project. Also using JDeveloper 11g as the IDE.

As you can infer, it has no problem being compiled.

My problem is as follow:

When my `deployment profile` has a fault and it doesn't include the **MyUtils.jar** in the output `war` file, after deploying and running the web project, it gives me the `ClassCircularityError`. But when I manually add the **MyUtils.jar** to the output `war` file, it runs without any error.

I'm confused why this situation results in `ClassCircularityError` and for example why it doesn't give me a `NoClassDefFoundError`? I'm asking this because I've read some documentations about `ClassCircularityError` and it wasn't even near to my situation of getting it.

I can't find out why this situation happening in `ADF` kind of project and every time I miss some dependency library in the `war` file I get this error and it is not only for this **MyUtils.jar** library.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is MyUtils.jar also a ADF project?

Comment: @GökhanÇoban: No it is not an ADF jar file.